# Geolib Cannot read property 'latitude' of undefined

Tags: javascript, geolocation, location, geo

This code has worked in the past on my server.  It also works on my client with Geolib 2.0.9.  I'm currently using Geolib 2.0.18 on my server and I keep getting the following error:
Cannot read property 'latitude' of undefined

Here is my code:

```
var location = { _latitude: 37.49, _longitude: -122.26 }
var locations = [ { _latitude: 37.76, _longitude: -122.44 },
  { _latitude: 37.79, _longitude: -122.42 },
  { _latitude: 37.49, _longitude: -122.26 },
  { _latitude: 37.49, _longitude: -122.26 },
  { _latitude: 37.49, _longitude: -122.26 } ]

var testIssue = _.compact(_.map(locations, function(n){
                   if (25 >= (geolib.getDistance(location, n) / 1609.34)) {
                        return n;})
                    } else {
                        return;
                    }}));
```

Comment: `geolib.getDistance()` expects `location` to have properties `latitude` and `longtitude` but you are passing `_latitude` `_longitude` instead?

Comment: Thanks. You're on to something.  I'm not sure why this didn't throw an error before or rather why it's throwing an error now. I have to get dinner but will follow up on this soon. I've been staring at this for almost 3 hours! You are a life saver.

Comment: @Griffith That is the problem.  A similar problem arose recently and I'm tying it back to implementing class level permissions on my Parse db. For some reason the data is being returned in a slightly different way. Without Parse permissions _latitude and _longitude are actually wrapped as geopoints and interrpreted as such by Geolib but with Parse class level permissions on the data comes out as just a regular function with _latitude and _longitude and that is why Geolib rejects it. Any word on how to address this?